# opencv python color detection with boolean output

Tags: python, opencv, color-detection

i use this Script for color detection:

# import the necessary packages

```
    import numpy as np
    import argparse
    import cv2
```

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

# load the image

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
```

# define the list of boundaries

```
boundaries = [
        ([100,50,220],[135,80,245]),
]
```

# loop over the boundaries

```
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
        # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
        lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
        upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

        # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
        # the mask
        mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
        output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
        print (output)

        # show the images
        cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([image, output]))
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I need a boolean Variable for color detect or not.
How can I do that?

regards
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

here my own solution:

# import the necessary packages

```
import shutil
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
```

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

# load the image

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
```

# define the list of boundaries

```
boundaries = [
        ([100,50,220],[135,80,245]),
]
```

# loop over the boundaries

```
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
```

# create NumPy arrays from the boundaries

```
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")
```

# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply the mask

```
        mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
        if np.sum(mask) < 100:
         shutil.move(args["image"], "/temp/")
```

regards
Thomas